# Azure API - Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I have deployed my ASP.net core API on Azure  (app service). This API is supposed to fetch data per group of hospitals and import it into Azure SQL. (same region, connection: managed Identity). It works fine for small hospitals which have 100 records. But I get the below error for more than 100 records. (session time out is set to 6min)
**Error: 502 - The web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server**
any advice or suggestion to help me on this issue?
Note: The API works fine when I connect from my dev env to the DB.
Thank you

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information to enable us to help you. Like some (relevant) source code. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: you could have a look at accepting the input and using messaging to asynchronously process the information. This enables you to send out an OK real quick, but process the information asynchronously (for instance with a Function).

Comment: @rickvdbosch Thanks for your reply. my code is asp.net core API (c#). I found now, that when I call the endpoint to update the SQL, although I got the gateway error after 100 records, but it is still running and updating/adding records in SQL
Code Details
504
Undocumented
Error: Gateway Time-out
Response body
Download
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->